# Magento seasonal products

Tags: magento

I'm looking for an easy way to set up a product in the Magento catalog so that it appears on a date that I specify and only until a date I specify. This would operate similarly to the current sale_from and sale_to dates, but hide the products entirely outside the given date range. For reference, this is for holiday products that are only relevant until a given date. Anyone?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create two attributes, and if one of them is set, set the visibility accordingly use an event right before the save (using an event observer)...

Comment: Wouldn't I need to manually resave the products when their timers came due in that case?

Comment: You're right, I think a cronjob would also be needed. I advise you to look at how the price_from_date/price_to_date system works.